# Thymeleaf not processing templates properly

Tags: java, spring, controller, thymeleaf

I have been developing a simple project with frontend and backend for managing the university IT tickets. After implementing different approaches (and all of them working well) being the last using Spring and a MySQL database we needed to do it using thymeleaf but for some reason it does not save nor display the info. I've checked and the paths and password for the database in the application.properties are correct and all dependencies are in the pom.xml. Here is the code:

TicketController :

```
package ch.supsi.webapp.web.controller;

import ch.supsi.webapp.web.model.Status;
import ch.supsi.webapp.web.model.Ticket;
import ch.supsi.webapp.web.repository.TicketRepository;
import ch.supsi.webapp.web.service.TicketService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Controller

public class TicketController  {

    TicketService service;


    public TicketController(TicketRepository repository,TicketService service) {
        this.service=service;
    }




    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("tickets",service.list());
        //model.addAttribute("openTickets", service.findLast5ByStatus(Status.OPEN));
        //model.addAttribute("closedTickets", service.findLast5ByStatus(Status.CLOSED));
        return "index";
    }


    @PostMapping("/ticket/new")
    public String newPost(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("ticket", new Ticket());
        model.addAttribute("isNew", true);
        model.addAttribute("authors", service.getAuthors());
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @PostMapping("/ticket/new")
    public String post(Ticket ticket) throws IOException {
        service.save(ticket);
        return "redirect:/";
    }




}
```

Ticket Service

```
package ch.supsi.webapp.web.service;
import ch.supsi.webapp.web.model.Status;
import ch.supsi.webapp.web.model.Ticket;
import ch.supsi.webapp.web.repository.TicketRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import ch.supsi.webapp.web.model.Author;
import ch.supsi.webapp.web.repository.AuthorRepository;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class TicketService {

    private final TicketRepository repository;
    private final AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    public TicketService(TicketRepository ticketRepository, AuthorRepository authorRepository) {
        this.repository = ticketRepository;
        this.authorRepository = authorRepository;
    }
    public void save(Ticket ticket) {
        repository.save(ticket);
    }


    public void remove(long id) {
        repository.deleteById((int) id);
    }

    public Optional<Ticket> read(long id){
       return repository.findById((int) id);
    }
    public  List<Ticket> list() {
        return (List<Ticket>) repository.findAll();
    }

   public void update(long id , Ticket ticket){
       Optional<Ticket> optionalTicket = repository.findById((int) id);
      // Optional<Ticket> optionalAuthor = repository.findById(ticket.getAuthor());
           Ticket existingTicket = optionalTicket.get();
           //existingTicket.setAuthor(ticket.getAuthor());
           existingTicket.setTitle(ticket.getTitle());
           existingTicket.setDescription(ticket.getDescription());
           repository.save(existingTicket);

    }

    public List<Ticket> findLast5ByStatus(Status ticketStatus){
        return repository.findByStatusOrderByDateDesc(ticketStatus);



    }
    public List<Author> getAuthors() {
        return (List<Author>) authorRepository.findAll();}
    public boolean exists(int id) {
        return repository.existsById(id);
    }

}
```

TicketRepository

```
package ch.supsi.webapp.web.repository;

import ch.supsi.webapp.web.model.Status;
import ch.supsi.webapp.web.model.Ticket;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;


@Repository
public interface TicketRepository extends CrudRepository<Ticket, Integer>
{
    List<Ticket> findByStatusOrderByDateDesc(Status ticketStatus);
    //public Ticket findTicket(long id);

    //public void setChanges(Ticket ticket);
}
```

/ticket/new.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <img alt="SUPSI" height="32" src="https://www.supsi.ch/o/supsi-theme/images/supsi-logo.svg" width="117">
    <h1>SUPSI Tickets</h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <hr>
    <a th:href="@{/static}">Home</a> |
    <a>New ticket</a> |
    <hr>
</nav>
<form method="post" th:action="@{/ticket/new}"  th:object="${ch.supsi.webapp.web.model.Ticket}">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New ticket</legend>
        <div>
            <label >Title:
            <input th:field="*{title}" type="text">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="author">Author:</label>
            <input id="author" class="form-select" th:field="*{author}">

        </div>
        <div >
            <label for="status">Status:</label>
            <select id="status" th:field="*{status}">
                <option th:each="status : ${T(ch.supsi.webapp.web.model.Status).values()}" th:value="${status.values()}" th:text="${status.values()}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="type">Type:</label>
            <select id="type" th:field="*{type}">
                <option th:each="type : ${T(ch.supsi.webapp.web.model.Type).values}" th:value="${type}" th:text="${type}">Bug</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label >Description:</label>
            <textarea th:field="*{description}"></textarea>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" th:value="${isNew} ? 'Create ticket':'Update ticket'">
</form>
<footer>
    <hr>
    <small>TICKETS Copyleft CC-by
        <time datetime="2022">2022</time>
        by L:S</small>
    <hr>
</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title> This is PP5 page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <div class="item"> <a href="index.html" >Home</a></div>
            <div class="item"><a  th:href="@{/ticket/new}" href="ticket/new.html" >New Ticket </a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href="ticket1Details.html">Ticket 1 details</a></div>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <header >
        <h2>Welcome ! </h2>
    </header>
    <main>
    <div> <h2> Ticket management system </h2></div>
        <section>
            <h2>Open tickets</h2>
            <article th:each="ticket : ${tickets}">
                <span th:text="${#dates.format(ticket.date, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm')}"></span>
                <h3 th:text="${ticket.getTitle()}">Il primo ticket</h3>
                <a th:href="@{'/ticket/'+${ticket.getId()}}">view</a>
                <a th:href="@{'/ticket/'+${ticket.getId()}+'/edit'}">edit</a>
            </article>
            <article th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(openTickets)}">There's no ticket. Yippee!</article>
        </section>
        <aside rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css">
        <p>This is PP5 sidebar</p>
    </aside>
    </main>
    <footer rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css">
        <h3> This is the footer </h3>
        <p> Copyleft CC-by 2023 by Patricia </p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code won't run as you're mapping the resource "/ticket/new" more than one time, so Spring does not know which method to invoke.